# add php to href bootstrap carousel

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do my bootstrap carousel dynamic, so I put php code in the href so the URL can be updated without need to get into the code, but when I put the php code it only shows the image who has the class=active, so if I do clic in "next" it appears the carousel without image, but if I do "Inspect element" in the browser the image is there.

Here is my code, Hope you can help me.

```
<div id="ContieneCarousel">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" Data-Interval="7000">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
<li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
<?php echo "<a href='".$row['url']."'>" ?><img src="_admin/uploads/banner1.jpg"   title="MM1" alt="MM1" class="img-responsive" /><?php "</a>"; ?>
</div>

<div class="item">
<a href=""><img src="_admin/uploads/banner2.jpg" title="MM1" alt="MM1" class="img-responsive" /></a>
</div>

<div class="item">
<a href=""><img src="_admin/uploads/banner3.jpg" title="MM1" alt="MM1" class="img-responsive" /></a>
</div>

</div>

<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide = "prev">
<span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>

<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide = "next">
<span class="icon-next"></span>
</a>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't echo out the end a tag! So change this: `<?php "</a>"; ?>` to `<?= "</a>"; ?>`

Comment: this is also a good case for`printf`: `<?php printf('<a href="%s"><img src="%s"   title="MM1" alt="MM1" class="img-responsive"/></a>', $row['url'], '_admin/uploads/banner1.jpg'); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first verify if that file is a php file ;
then change you code with this an try ;

```
<?php 
$url = $row['url'] ;// test if URL is getted
if($url){
$html =  "<a href='$url'><img src='_admin/uploads/banner1.jpg'   title='MM1' alt='MM1' class='img-responsive' /></a>";
}else{
echo "URl not getted ";
}
?>
<div class="item active">
<?php echo $html ; ?>
</div>
```